# NHibernate monitor connections

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way to monitor the round-trips to the database in an NHibernate application?
I need just a log to see when NHibernate connects to database.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [NHibernate Profiler](http://www.nhprof.com/) (NHProf) if you don't mind a commercial product. Some of its features are:

- Visual insight into the interaction between your database and application code.
- Analysis and detection of common pitfalls when using NHibernate.
- Analysis is delivered via perfectly styled SQL and linkable code execution.
- Supports NHibernate (.NET) and Hibernate (Java).

Answer (score 4):

You can 'monitor' via logging using NH's log4net. Some useful info [here](https://www.hibernate.org/364.html).

That will be monitor from the application side.

Have you tried monitoring from the DB serverside? E.g. enable logging at the say mySql.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to NHProf and log4net, there is also a "show_sql" config entry that will dump the SQL to the console in a console app.

Your database vendor should also have tools for monitoring the SQL that is being run against it.